# How does apache spark allocate tasks in the following scenario with mapPartitions?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Given the following Apache Spark (Python) code (it is working):

```
import sys
from random import random
from operator import add
import sqlite3
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

from pyspark import SparkContext


def agePartition(recs):
    gconn = sqlite3.connect('/home/chris/test.db')
    myc = gconn.cursor()
    today = date.today()
    return_part = []
    for rec in recs:
        sql = "select birth_date from peeps where name = '{n}'".format(n=rec[0])
        myc.execute(sql)
        bdrec = myc.fetchone()
        born = datetime.strptime(bdrec[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
        return_part.append( (rec[0], today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))) )
    gconn.close()
    return iter(return_part)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
        Usage: pi [partitions]
    """
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonDBTEST")
    print('starting...')
    data = [('Chris', 1), ('Amanda', 2), ('Shiloh', 2), ('Sammy', 2), ('Tim', 1)]
    rdd = sc.parallelize(data,5) 
    rslt_collect = rdd.mapPartitions(agePartition).collect()

    for x in rslt_collect:
        print("{n} is {a}".format(n=x[0], a=x[1]))

    sc.stop()
```

In a two compute / slave node setup with a total of 8 cpus would each of the partitions be created as a task and allocated to the 2 nodes so that all 5 partitions run in parallel? If not, what more would need to be done to make sure that happens?

The intent here was testing keeping a global database connection alive per slave work process so the database connection doesn't have to be re-opened for each record in the RDD that gets processed.  I'm using SQLite in this example but it will be a SQLCipher database and that has is a lot more time consuming to open on the database connection.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing it this way and not using a `JdbcRDD` or something similar?

Comment: The short answer is yes.  As mentioned I've got it working and the intent is to keep a db connection open rather than have a new connection opened for each record that gets processed (assuming I had more than five records in my initial RDD).  The existing non-spark process runs in parallel on a single computer and breaks the data to be processed into a list for each CPU, opens a connection per cpu and then processes the list.  If a connection had to be opened for each record then it would be extremely slow...

Comment: ...This code I posted gets around that problem in a spark context but I'm trying to understand how each partition gets handled.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your expectation is.  Let's say that you have **10 records** in `data`, a **2-node cluster**, and a total of **8 cores** (4 per node).   Is your expectation **a)** create 10 connections (1 per record in data) **b)** create 2 connections (1 per node) or **c)** create 8 connections (1 per core) ?

Comment: Thank you for the interaction.  My expectation would be one per core so that if the number of records were much greater I would not be continually recreating database connections.

Comment: Got it.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 8 available slots (cpus) in the cluster.  You can process up to 8 partitions concurrently.  In your case, you have 5 partitions, so they should all be processed in parallel.  This would be 5 concurrent connections to the database.

> My expectation would be one per core so that if the number of records were much greater I would not be continually recreating database connections.

In your case, it will be per partition.  If you have 20 partitions and 8 cores, you will still create the connection 20 times.